# How to config nginx and uwsgi to cache a url any way?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Update2: add `uwsgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Set-Cookie X-Accel-Expires Expires Vary;` and problem solved. Thanks everyone.

Update: I tried `uwsgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Set-Cookie X-Accel-Expires Expires Vary;`. Doesnot work. I also find that, if I make same request in the logout state from different browsers on the same computer, the cache still doesnot work. This is really silly...

I've seen the comments below, but I don't know how to apply it to the config file.

I want to cache url `/`, it works well but I find that if I login or logout, the cache doesnot work. why? I just want to cache `/` anyway. Here is my cofiguration:

```
uwsgi_cache_path uwsgi_cache_path /app/path/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:1m max_size=50m inactive=30m use_temp_path=off;

server {
...

    location = / {
        uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:3032; 
        include     /app/path/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_cache my_cache;
        uwsgi_cache_key "$host$uri$is_args$args";

        uwsgi_cache_valid 5m;

    }
...

}
```

Comment: Most likely your UWSGI app is sending some headers that forbid nginx to cache the content. Ideally you should remove those from the app or set nginx to ignore them.

Comment: You would have to post the headers of those requests and the contents of /app/path/uwsgi_params

Comment: @JayMcTee could you be more detailed? how to implement this in the nginx config file?

Comment: I was saying you need to be more detailed. You need to post the contents of that include file plus ideally some example headers of requests where this behaviour occurs.